# Difference between BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator and DataFlowPythonOperator in apache airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to run a job in Airflow which executes a dataflow job. I realized there are 2 Operators, that are BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator and DataFlowPythonOperator, both operators can submit jobs to dataflow, but i have concern about the difference between them.
Is there any difference between them? Please help me. Any help would be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFlowPythonOperator` was deprecated and replaced by `DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator` which was then deprecated and replaced by `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator`.

TLDR; use `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` as of July 2022.